# Hibernate : queries with multiple tables

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and working on a project where I need to extract data from DB using complex query. So just for example :
Let there are tables Student, Attendance, Subject and so on ..
Student contains (name(assume primary key),class,age,sex .. and other student data).
Attendance contains (student name, % attendance).
Subject contains (student , subjects )

I need to extract data for queries like

q1: (age > 20 && age < 22)

q2: class == Engineering

q3: should contain algorithm as it's subject.
student with  (q1||q2) && q3.

Even query can be even more complex. like ((q1&&q2)||(q3&&q4)) && q5 ..

I have few questions:
Assuming all table have same primary key(and I am taking join on that).

1. What is best and most efficient way to do it.
2. is it possible to write single query for such complex expression and if possible is it 
   recommended ?
3. If it is not possible to write a single query for it. I can think of calculating it like a postfix expression, seems dirty ?

4.My understanding is if q1 and q2 belongs to same table AND/OR in where clause will work but if they belong to different table if have to take join and then condition need to be applied. Right ?

If anything looks stupid in my question , I am sorry for that just 2 days back I started working on it.
Any good resource for read will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create quite complex queries with a single statement. You might want to look into sub queries.
As for whether it is recommended or not, it would all depend on execution plan which would require a pick at actual datasets.

hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Hibernate Criteria API is perfect for your purpose. You can see some examples in this articles:

http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm

Regards

Comment: second link only deals with single tables, not multiple